# Midnight in a formal context

Tags: time

Let's say I wrote in a message "… the deadline is Monday at 11 PM." but immediately changed my mind and decided to postpone the deadline by an hour.

What should I write? "Monday at 12 PM", "Tuesday at 0 AM", or something else? or is it just a matter of personal taste?

---

*Edit*:
The question is: what should I write, in a formal context and using AM/PM notation, to express the concept "1 hour later than Monday at 11 PM".

Comment: This is tricky. There are [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538754/what-does-after-midnight-on-wednesday-mean) on English Language and Usage, but it confuses native speakers too. "Midnight on Monday night" is clearer. (Midnight is always 12 am not 12 pm.)

Comment: It's a pet peeve of mine that people insist on saying '12 am/pm' instead of '12 noon/midnight'. (Since p.m. is _post meridiem_ - after noon - I always maintain that 12 pm should be midnight!)

Comment: That is my Pet Peeve too , @KateBunting , but I have seen even worse, like "1 PM Noon" or "11:30 PM Midnight" , which seem self-contradictory !!

Comment: @StuartF *"Midnight on Monday night" is clearer.* Agreed, but it sounds to me (of course a non-native speaker)  a little bit too colloquial in the formal context that I have introduced.

Comment: May I suggest using "11:59 am/pm"? This convention is used widely at my university because the meaning is 100% clear. (We actually use "23:59," but you get the idea.)

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123463/is-the-midnight-in-english-12-a-m-or-12-p-m-or-both?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C42.6741

Answer (score 1):

In a 12-hour system, midnight is typically written as 12 AM and noon as 12 PM. Most people would understand and be familiar with this convention.

However, as Kate Bunting wrote in a comment, this isn't technically accurate, since "AM" stands for "ante meridiem," or "before midday," and "PM" stands for "post meridiem," or "after midday." Since noon and midnight are neither before or after midday, to be the most accurate you can say "12 noon" or "12 midnight," both of which can be used in a formal context.

In a 24-hour system, you can get rid of all of the confusion and inaccuracy, since midnight is 00:00 or 24:00 and noon is 12:00.

Comment: Re 24 hours system, Monday at 00:00 is followed by Tuesday at 00:01 or by Monday at 00:01?

Comment: Re: midnight tipically written as 12 AM — I find this completely illogical (I'm not saying your answer is wrong, just that it sounds illogical to me :-)

Comment: sorry, 12 midnight is always the next day already. So after 11:59 PM on Monday comes 12:00 AM on Tuesday. Same with the 24-hour system, 00:00 is already Tuesday.